# Replacing string in a script using sed

Tags: linux, gnu

I am new in using sed command and I have an sql which contains "MONYY" and I want to change the "MONYY" in the file by replacing it with the current "MONYY" automatically.

I have used the following command and I am able to get previous month and year and current month and year in uppercase and now I am trying to replace the values in my script using sed command but nothing is happening.

```
date1=$ date +"%b%y"|sed 's/\(.*\)/\U\1/'

echo $date1

date2=$ date -d ' -1 month ' +"%b%y"|sed 's/\(.*\)/\U\1/'

echo $date2

sed 's/$date1/$date2/g' aggdom.sql > temp
```

Can anyone help me out with the sed command that I am using

Answer (score 1):

The script above will substitute every `$date1` with `$date2`

but the result will be printed in `temp` file

If you want to change the strings in `aggdom.sql`

you have to change the line to something like that:

```
sed -i 's/$date1/$date2/g' aggdom.sql
```

from `sed` man page:

> -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>
> ```
>          edit files in place (makes backup if extension  supplied).   The
>           default  operation  mode  is  to  break symbolic and hard links.
>           This can be changed with --follow-symlinks and --copy.
> ```

on some operating system you have to add  `-e` as an option:

```
sed -i -e s/$date1/$date2/g aggdom.sql
```

Comment: Hello Networker, you were right the first time.  I am trying to every $date1 with $date2 into another file.  But I have tried the command you have provided and still no changes is being found in aggdom.sql.  The date remains as it was.

Comment: what the OS you are using

Comment: I am using GNU/Linux

Comment: even when adding -e also its the same.  Is there any other command that I can use instead of sed?